# Rails upgrading to bootstrap 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I'm currently using bootstrap 3.3.7 and trying to upgrade to 4.0.0.beta2 but after following this tutorial https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem I receive the below error.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
```

here's my gemfile

```
# bootstrap
# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
```

I ran

```
gem install bootstrap -v 4.0.0.beta2
```

Here's the out from running bundle update, I'm using a version of sprockets-rails 2.3.2.

```
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.1.4
```

here's what i have in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; 
@import "bootstrap";
@import "colors";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

my application.js file

```
//
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require turbolinks
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

If I remove @import "bootstrap-sprockets"; from application.scss the web app comes up but I would like to know if it's needed or why i'm getting the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Bootstrap Sprockets provides individual Bootstrap components for ease of debugging.

Read the instructions again in the [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) and you'll notice there isn't suppose to be an import for bootstrap-sprockets.

`// app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";  // Remove this line`

There is however suppose to be a javascript require for it. This can be substituted with a require for just bootstrap for faster compilation (which you're currently doing).

So basically, remove that line from the scss and you're good.